# If You Don't Want to Make a Fire Fighter Angry

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

...here's what you do:

[image]

A full explanation will be awarded the "Correct Answer."

Hint:

> Those who don't ["do this"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36559/if-you-dont-want-to-make-a-fire-fighter-angry) are a bunch of [lazy](https://www.google.com/search?q=lazy+definition&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl), [good-for-nothing](https://www.google.com/search?q=shiftless&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl#q=good+for+nothing+definition), [shiftless](https://www.google.com/search?q=shiftless&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl) [layabouts](https://www.google.com/search?q=lazy+definition&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl#q=layabout+definition)!

HINT#2

> I'm certain that "shiftless" is a word.  Is "shiftfull" a thing? +1 (or minus one) to the one who can define "shift."

Hint #3

> [to the left, to the right](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkplPbd2f60)

Comment: Give him way to the fire spot.

Comment: The light are flashing in some pattern, maybe morses?

Comment: The 8 yellow flashlights look very binary (?) to me if taken in each frame?

Comment: Maybe a [useful view](http://gif-explode.com/?explode=http://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ1iw.gif) on the data. (Frames split)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> KEEPBACK500FEET!

by

> taking the binary codes provided by Gintas for every other frame, shifting the ones either one spot left or one spot right based on the top lights, converting to decimal, then converting to ascii.

---

In detail:

> `+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+`
>  `| Direction | Initial Binary | Shifted Binary | Decimal | Ascii Character |`
>  `+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+`
>  `| Right     | 1001 0110      | 0100 1011      |      75 | K               |`
>  `| Right     | 1000 1010      | 0100 0101      |      69 | E               |`
>  `| Right     | 1000 1010      | 0100 0101      |      69 | E               |`
>  `| Left      | 0010 1000      | 0101 0000      |      80 | P               |`
>  `| Left      | 0010 0001      | 0100 0010      |      66 | B               |`
>  `| Right     | 1000 0010      | 0100 0001      |      65 | A               |`
>  `| Right     | 1000 0110      | 0100 0011      |      67 | C               |`
>  `| Right     | 1001 0110      | 0100 1011      |      75 | K               |`
>  `| Right     | 0110 1010      | 0011 0101      |      53 | 5               |`
>  `| Left      | 0001 1000      | 0011 0000      |      48 | 0               |`
>  `| Left      | 0001 1000      | 0011 0000      |      48 | 0               |`
>  `| Left      | 0010 0011      | 0100 0110      |      70 | F               |`
>  `| Right     | 1000 1010      | 0100 0101      |      69 | E               |`
>  `| Right     | 1000 1010      | 0100 0101      |      69 | E               |`
>  `| Left      | 0010 1010      | 0101 0100      |      84 | T               |`
>  `| Right     | 0100 0010      | 0010 0001      |      33 | !               |`
>  `+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+`

Comment: Is the decimal step really necessary?

Comment: @f'' Not really.  But I was working with the numbers in excel which has binary>dec and dec>ascii functions so I thought I would show the steps I actually used.

Comment: Good answer! I've taken the liberty of converting the code block to a spoiler-tagged fake code block, which really is a multi-line spoiler block with inline code markup in backticks. Please revert the edit if that isn't what you want.

Answer (score 7):

**Partial**

Light flashing by frame:

```
FRAME      TOP LIGHTS       BOTTOM LIGHTS
0           0000 1111         1001 0110
1           0000 0000         0000 0000
2           0000 1111         1000 1010
3           0000 0000         0000 0000
4           0000 1111         1000 1010
5           0000 0000         0000 0000
6           1111 0000         0010 1000
7           0000 0000         0000 0000
8           1111 0000         0010 0001
9           0000 0000         0000 0000
10          0000 1111         1000 0010
11          0000 0000         0000 0000
12          0000 1111         1000 0110
13          0000 0000         0000 0000
14          0000 1111         1001 0110
15          0000 0000         0000 0000
16          0000 1111         0110 1010
17          0000 0000         0000 0000
18          1111 0000         0001 1000
19          0000 0000         0000 0000
20          1111 0000         0001 1000
21          0000 0000         0000 0000
22          1111 0000         0010 0011
23          0000 0000         0000 0000
24          0000 1111         1000 1010
25          0000 0000         0000 0000
26          0000 1111         1000 1010
27          0000 0000         0000 0000
28          1111 0000         0010 1010
29          0000 0000         0000 0000
30          0000 1111         0100 0010
31          0000 0000         0000 0000
```

As we can see every second frame is with all light off, so we remove them and get:

```
FRAME      TOP LIGHTS       BOTTOM LIGHTS
0           0000 1111         1001 0110
2           0000 1111         1000 1010
4           0000 1111         1000 1010
6           1111 0000         0010 1000
8           1111 0000         0010 0001
10          0000 1111         1000 0010
12          0000 1111         1000 0110
14          0000 1111         1001 0110
16          0000 1111         0110 1010
18          1111 0000         0001 1000
20          1111 0000         0001 1000
22          1111 0000         0010 0011
24          0000 1111         1000 1010
26          0000 1111         1000 1010
28          1111 0000         0010 1010
30          0000 1111         0100 0010
```

The top lights are always on or off all together and only on one side:

```
FRAME      TOP LIGHTS       BOTTOM LIGHTS
0            RIGHT            1001 0110
2            RIGHT            1000 1010
4            RIGHT            1000 1010
6            LEFT             0010 1000
8            LEFT             0010 0001
10           RIGHT            1000 0010
12           RIGHT            1000 0110
14           RIGHT            1001 0110
16           RIGHT            0110 1010
18           LEFT             0001 1000
20           LEFT             0001 1000
22           LEFT             0010 0011
24           RIGHT            1000 1010
26           RIGHT            1000 1010
28           LEFT             0010 1010
30           RIGHT            0100 0010
```

NOTES:

> Every `LEFT` starts with `00`
>
> Every `RIGHT` ends with `10`

Comment: +1 for doing the translation. The "rhythm" of the top-lights is not regular. I woud be very surprised if this is not of importance, so I don't think your arguemnt for using LEFT/RIGHT andd then just skipping is valid?

Comment: @Chowzen , a hint maybe? :)

Comment: bottom lights seem to be a trinary code, same as top lights.  each pair is either `01`  `10` or `00`

Comment: @Jasen , it has `11` on frame `22` ?

Comment: @GintasK I think that progress is being made. +1s to Bmy & Gintas for their dissection to this point. A great scholar once said, 
"Posting hints late causes only delays.
I would therefore advise to refrain from adding hints as long as possible, which, essentially, depends on your patience. Some very good puzzles have remained unsolved for months, but eventually, somebody solved them." That being said, *I'm certainly open to hinting if progress stagnates.*

Comment: @GintasK You need to edit your post. You numbered the 32 pictures in a zero-based fashion, from 0 to 32, which yields **33** translations for **32** pictures..

Comment: If you read the "right" ones right-to-left, they are all in the range of ASCII letters.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Yes, those numbers match the pictures.